# How to use Plain JS in angular js expression?

Tags: angularjs

IN JS, 
i have object as

```
var type = {};
type.showBox = false;
```

Using angular, i have to hide the input box.
It can be easily achieved by

```
$scope object ( "$scope.type.showBox = false;" )
```

But i want to use plain js in angular expression

```
<input type="text" ng-show="{{ type.showBox == true }}"/>
```

Comment: use ng-init nearest, but still angular expression, not real javascript.

Comment: ng-show will only show if the expression returns true... so the input box will be visible if your variable, type.showBox has a value of true. There is no need for an extra check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant, however what you can do, and in my opinion is going to be much cleaner, is to write a function in your controller

```
$scope.shouldShowBox=function(){
return $scope.type===true
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Remember that interpolation will display the output of the expression. So you have created an expression but not specified any output.

What you're looking for is:

`ng-show="{{ type.showBox ? 'true' : 'false' }}"`

However you don't need to interpolate (and it's probably better if you don't). All you need is:

`ng-show="type.showBox"`